# Firebase. Ограничение доступа к данным

Tags: база-данных, firebase

-Имеются несколько устройств, отправляющих данные в базу firebase.

-Каждое устройство имеет номер и секретный ключ.

-Пользователь может иметь несколько устройств и одну учётную запись, зарегистрированную в проекте.

Нужно ограничить доступ к данным устройств для пользователей так, чтобы они имели возможность получить их только предъявив секретный ключ каждого из опрашиваемых устройств.

Например, структура данных устройств, хранящихся в базе данных такая:

```
project_name
    devices
        id_001
            secret_code: xxxxx
            measurenments:
                -KXjSFiSmGEhWXGig_Xe
                    data1: 42
                    data2: "qwe"
                -KXjSFiSmGEhWXGig_Xf
                    data1: 11
                    data2: "zxc"
        id_002
            secret_code: yyyyy
                measurenments:
```

Структура может быть переделана по необходимости. Нужна помощь в составлении файла rules для базы данных.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае надо прописывать роли для каждого id_001...id_N но это скорее всего не подойдет, я бы использовал другую структуру хранения

```
project_name
    devices
       secret_code: xxxxx
         id_001
            measurenments:
                -KXjSFiSmGEhWXGig_Xe
                    data1: 42
                    data2: "qwe"
                -KXjSFiSmGEhWXGig_Xf
                    data1: 11
                    data2: "zxc"
      secret_code: yyyyy
        id_002                
                measurenments:
```

В этом случае права будут выглядеть как-то так

```
{  
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true, 

    "devices":{
      ".read": true,
      ".write":true,
              "$secret_code": {
               ".read": "auth != null
               ".write": "auth != null && data.parent().getKey().val() == $secret_code"
               }       

     }
```

}
}

более подробно здесь https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data